# Random uint8_t number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to be able to generate a random number between 01-30 as a uint8_t in Objective-C.

So for example it will be like any of the following:

```
uint8_t randomNumber1 = 0x13;
uint8_t randomNumber2 = 0x04;
uint8_t randomNumber3 = 0x22;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `0x22` (from your example) is larger than 30 (base-10), I'll assume your upper bound is `0x30`. In that case,

```
uint8_t random = arc4random_uniform(0x30) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Warren. As I mentioned to Vladimir below, I should have mentioned in my question that I need the number to stay as 0X13, or 0X22, or 0X04 opposed to something like '\x18' as it shows me in the debugger log. Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: That's just an artifact of how it's presented by the debugger. Are you asking how to print the value formatted as a hex number?

Comment: Ah nvm my mistake. I appreciate all your help, will accept!

Answer (score 1):

You can use arc4random_uniform function to generate random number in given interval:

```
uint8_t randomNumber1 = (uint8_t)arc4random_uniform(30) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I should have mentioned in my question that I need the number to stay as 0X13, or 0X22, or 0X04 opposed to something like '\x18' as it shows me in the debugger log. Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: It is just a way debugger displays uint8_t variable by default. If you want to print it differently you can use custom format string in NSLog. Or if you want to change debugger default behavior you can look into lldb scripting api